# Is there a safe alternative to replace the unsafe slice::from_raw_parts for raw pointers?

Tags: pointers, rust, memcpy, memory-safety

I have a Rust dynamic library which is intended to be called from any language. The arguments to the exported function are two `char *` pointers to memory and two lengths for each piece of memory.

The problem is that `from_raw_parts` reduces to a memcpy and can segfault in a variety of dangerous ways if for example the lengths are wrong. I'm then using `bincode::deserialize` on the slices to use them as Rust objects. Is there any safer option to deal with incoming raw pointers to memory?

Comment: So your question is "how can I trust or check a pointer"? You can't. That's pretty much why Rust's `unsafe` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

What you are asking doesn't make sense. To some level, the entire reason that *Rust the language* exists is because raw pointers are inherently dangerous. Rust's references (and their related lifetimes) are a structured way of performing compile-time checks to ensure that a pointer is valid and safe to use.

Once you start using raw pointers, the compiler can no longer help you with those pointers and it's now up to **you** to ensure that safety is guaranteed.

---

> `from_raw_parts` reduces to a memcpy

This doesn't seem correct. No memory should be copied to create a slice. A Rust slice is effectively just a pair of `(pointer, length)` — the same things that you are passing in separately. I'd expect those each to be register-sized, so calling `memcpy` would be overkill.

*Using the resulting slice* could possibly involve copying the data, but that's not due to `from_raw_parts` anymore.